# Model::count() returns error in Query scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using `count()` method to count rows in a model. It works if i use it directly like this:

```
return Model::count();
```

But when I try to use it from Query scope, I am getting an error:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

Query scope in Model:

```
public function scopecountUsers($query) {
    return $query->count();
}
```

Can anyone explain why it is so?

There are **no rows** in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is the way scopes are handled in Eloquent builder. If you have a look at the Builder's code, you can see the following method:

```
protected function callScope($scope, $parameters)
{
    array_unshift($parameters, $this);
    return call_user_func_array([$this->model, $scope], $parameters) ?: $this;
}
```

As you can see, if the scope method returns a **truthy value** (a value that evaluates to true when cast to boolean), then this value is a result of calling the scope. On the other hand, if the returned value evaluates to false, the **builder object is returned instead**. In your case, as you have no rows in the table, scope's return value is 0, that's why you're getting the builder object as a result of `Model::countUsers()`.

If you cannot guarantee that a scope will always return a truthy value, it's not a good idea to return anything from the scope method. My suggestion is to use scopes only to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application, as the documentation suggests, not to execute queries. Some examples:

```
Model::someScope()->get();
Model::someScope()->someOtherScope()->count();
```